# Sign of permutation who discovered that

Tags: permutations, math-history, symmetric-groups, permutation-cycles, permutation-matrices

I am reading a book about mathematical games. One game is the 15 puzzle https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/15_puzzle
The answer whether it is solvable or not, was solved by using sign of permutations.

My question: Does anyone of you know who was the first human who discovered the principle of sign of a permutation (number of inversions)? And how did the person discover it? Was it because of this game?

Comment: For math history questions, you can also ask in https://hsm.stackexchange.com/ for possibly more success.

Comment: References 1,3, and 4 on [this page](https://www.maa.org/press/periodicals/loci/joma/parity-theorem-for-permutations-references) seem like they might have an answer

Comment: Based on [this wiki page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/History_of_group_theory), the formal study of group theory (including permutations) dates back to the early 1800s, whereas the 15 puzzle has only been around since, at earliest, 1874. My bet is that permutations (and their parity) were well understood by the mathematical community by the time the puzzle was invented.

Comment: If you read french, here is a seminal memoir by Cauchy (1815) elaborating the concept of permutation "acting" on a formula: https://gallica.bnf.fr/ark:/12148/bpt6k90193x/f78.item

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Short answer: probably Cauchy.

Long answer: a bit of Googling "parity of permutations" eventually turns up this [proof of the parity theorem for permutations](https://www.maa.org/press/periodicals/loci/joma/parity-theorem-for-permutations-introduction) by John Kiltinen, which has a [pedagogical sidebar](https://www.maa.org/sites/default/files/images/upload_library/4/vol1/parity/ParityJOKHistory.html) saying how different textbooks prove this theorem.  In that sidebar Kiltinen says that Gallian, in his algebra textbook, says that the theorem is due to Cauchy. [Comtet also gives a proof](https://books.google.com/books?id=PJzuCAAAQBAJ&pg=PA232&lpg=PA232&dq=cauchy%201815%20parity&source=bl&ots=Fc7oQC5xv_&sig=ACfU3U3u5Cqhtzm9KTEImLKivY-EM31niQ&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiZuMCky4PwAhUWH80KHX66AJkQ6AEwCXoECAcQAw#v=onepage&q=cauchy%201815%20parity&f=false) due to Cauchy in 1815.  If you can read French, here's the [original Cauchy paper.](https://gallica.bnf.fr/ark:/12148/bpt6k90193x/f97) - see pp. 104-105 - Cauchy doesn't cite anybody here, as far as I can tell.

Comment: It is the same paper I just cited...